Prove Liouville theorem using Pohozaev identity
Given the PDE $$\Delta u+u^p=0 \qquad \text{in}\ \ \mathbb{R}^n,$$where $p\in (\frac{n}{n-2},\frac{n+2}{n-2})$. Suppose we have known the existence of a nonnegative radial solution, and I want to show that the solution must be zero.
I plan to apply the Pohozaev identity for any domain $\Omega$
$$n\int_\Omega \frac{u^{p+1}}{p+1}dx + \frac{2-n}{2}\int_\Omega |Du|^2dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\partial\Omega}\left|\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}\right|^2(x\cdot\nu)d\sigma(x).$$
For $\Omega = B_R(0)$, the LHS of Pohozaev identity turns to be $$\left(\frac{n}{p+1}+\frac{2-n}{2}\right)\int_{B_R}u^{p+1} = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\partial B_R}\left|\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}\right|^2(x\cdot\nu)d\sigma(x)\le \frac{n}{2}\omega_n\sup_{\partial B_R}|\nabla u|^2R^n.$$
Here $p<\frac{n+2}{n-2}$ leads to $\frac{n}{p+1}+\frac{2-n}{2}>0$.
I should derive an estimate like $\sup_{B_R}|\nabla u|^2 \le R^{-A}$ for some $A>0$, but I do not know how to do and am looking forward to your help.

Look, Pohozaev is not applicable here. Of course the very identity is right:
It follows that $$n\int_\Omega \frac{u^{p+1}}{p+1} dx + \frac{2-n}{2}\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\partial\Omega} |\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}|^2 (x\cdot\nu) d\sigma(x)$$
But to get out of this integral identity any pointwise estimate on $|∇u|$ from which you can deduce that the solution must be constant is likely going to be a nightmare if at all possible. Youtd have to do Moser iteration or something, overkill.
The actual trick is in scaling argument. Let $u_λ(x)=λ^{2/(p-1)}u(λx)$. If $u$ solves the PDE, then so does $u_λ$. Check it:
$$\Delta u_\lambda(x) + u_\lambda(x)^p = \lambda^{2+\frac{2p}{p-1}} \Delta u(\lambda x) + \lambda^{\frac{2p}{p-1}} u(\lambda x)^p = \lambda^{2+\frac{2p}{p-1}} [\Delta u(\lambda x) + u(\lambda x)^p] = 0$$
Now, $u$ is radial, hence $u(x) = u(|x|) = u(r)$ and it is nonnegative, $u(r) ≥ 0$. Assume that $u$ is nontrivial that is $u(r_0) > 0$ for some $r_0$. Now look at $u_λ$:
$$u_\lambda(\frac{r_0}{\lambda}) = \lambda^{\frac{2}{p-1}} u(r_0)$$ Since $p > \frac{n}{n-2} > 1$, as $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$, $u_\lambda(\frac{r_0}{\lambda})$ blows up to infinity. This is a bad thing to happen. There is only one way this could be avoided is if $u(r) = 0$ for all $r$, i.e., $u$ be the zero solution. The point is, combined with radial symmetry and nonnegativity, the scaling argument nails it. Avoids obscurant estimates by Pohozaev. Much cleaner this way. An exponent p < n +2 n - 2 is borderline, and scaling argument is the way to go.

Thanks for your suggestion! Scaling is a good tool here.
